# How to unzip a zip folder containing different file formats using Java

Tags: java, xml, unzip

I need to unzip a zipped directory containing different files' format like `.txt, .xml, .xls` etc.

I am able to unzip if the directory contains only `.txt files` but it fails with other files format. Below is the program that I am using and after a bit of googling, all I saw was similar approach -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class ZipUtils {
  public static void extractFile(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int l;
      while ((l = inStream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
           outStream.write(buf, 0, l);
      }
      inStream.close();
      outStream.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Enumeration enumEntries;
      ZipFile zip;

      try {
          zip = new ZipFile("myzip.zip");
          enumEntries = zip.entries();
          while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
              ZipEntry zipentry = (ZipEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();
              if (zipentry.isDirectory()) {
                  System.out.println("Name of Extract directory : " + zipentry.getName());
                  (new File(zipentry.getName())).mkdir();
                  continue;
              }
              System.out.println("Name of Extract fille : " + zipentry.getName());

              extractFile(zip.getInputStream(zipentry), new FileOutputStream(zipentry.getName()));
          }
          zip.close();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.out.println("There is an IoException Occured :" + ioe);
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Throws the below exception -

```
There is an IoException Occured :java.io.FileNotFoundException: myzip\abc.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myzip\abc.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at updaterunresults.ZipUtils.main(ZipUtils.java:43)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a good example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/) in which he showed to unzip all the formats (pdf, txt etc) have look its quite

or you can use this code might work (i haven't tried this)

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ZipUtils
{
  private static final int  BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

  private static void extractFile(ZipInputStream in, File outdir, String name) throws IOException
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outdir,name)));
    int count = -1;
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
      out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    out.close();
  }

  private static void mkdirs(File outdir,String path)
  {
    File d = new File(outdir, path);
    if( !d.exists() )
      d.mkdirs();
  }

  private static String dirpart(String name)
  {
    int s = name.lastIndexOf( File.separatorChar );
    return s == -1 ? null : name.substring( 0, s );
  }

  /***
   * Extract zipfile to outdir with complete directory structure
   * @param zipfile Input .zip file
   * @param outdir Output directory
   */
  public static void extract(File zipfile, File outdir)
  {
    try
    {
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipfile));
      ZipEntry entry;
      String name, dir;
      while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
      {
        name = entry.getName();
        if( entry.isDirectory() )
        {
          mkdirs(outdir,name);
          continue;
        }
        /* this part is necessary because file entry can come before
         * directory entry where is file located
         * i.e.:
         *   /foo/foo.txt
         *   /foo/
         */
        dir = dirpart(name);
        if( dir != null )
          mkdirs(outdir,dir);

        extractFile(zin, outdir, name);
      }
      zin.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: I guess that `dirpart()` can be replaced with [`File.getParentFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile())?

Comment: I told you i haven't tried this code, just one of my friend used it a long ago. well you think its better, then go with it :) Regards...

Comment: It was not a critique on your answer, but a suggestion/improvement!

Comment: Thanks @Veger. I am not taking it as critique but a helpful suggestion :) I will keep it in mind. Regards

Answer (score 3):

When you try to open the file that is going to contain the extracted content, the error occurs.
This is because the `myzip` folder is not available.

So check if it indeed is not available and create it before extracting the zip:

```
File outputDirectory = new File("myzip");
if(!outputDirectory.exists()){
    outputDirectory.mkdir();
}
```

---

As @[Perception](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680925/perception) pointed out in the comments: The output location is relative to the active/working directory. This is probably not very convenient, so you might want to add the extraction location to the location of the extracted files:

```
File outputLocation = new File(outputDirectory, zipentry.getName());
extractFile(zip.getInputStream(zipentry), new FileOutputStream(outputLocation));
```

(of course you need also add `outputLocation` to the directory creation code)

Comment: +1 for creating the directory. You might also want to point out that this will 'extract' the entry relative to the path the program is running in. It might be better to specify an absolute path.

Comment: @Perception hm... that is indeed another issue with the provided code